# Reference for smoothness of Nemytskii operator on fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth and bounded (together with all of its derivatives). Define the operator
$$
\big(N_\varphi x\big)(t)=\varphi\big(x(t)\big)
$$
for $x\in H^s(T^d)$, the fractional Sobolev space of order $s\in (0,\infty)$ over the $d$-dimensional torus. The following result seems to be well known, but I struggle to find a reference:

> For each $s>d/2$ the operator $N_\varphi:H^s(T^d)\to H^s(T^d)$ is infinitely often differentiable in the Frechet sense and, for each $k\geq 0$, $D^k N_\varphi$ is bounded over bounded sets in $H^s(T^d)$.